# Sparksql cut String after special position

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Hello what i want to do is to cut a URL so it is all in a specific Format.
At the Moment my URL Looks like this.

```
[https://url.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx]
```

I just want to cut everything after the third / and just Count my data so that i have an overview how much URLs i have in my data.

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined functions (UDFs) is what you need. Assume you have following input:

```
case class Data(url: String)
val urls = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(Data("http://google.com/q=dfsdf"), Data("https://fb.com/gsdgsd")))
urls.registerTempTable("urls")
```

Now you can define UDF that gets only hostname from URL:

```
def getHost(url: String) = url.split('/')(2) //naive implementation, for example only
sqlContext.udf.register("getHost", getHost _)
```

And get your data transformed using SQL:

```
val hosts = sqlContext.sql("select getHost(url) as host from urls")
hosts.show()
```

Result:

```
+----------+
|      host|
+----------+
|google.com|
|    fb.com|
+----------+
```

If you prefer Scala DSL, you can use your UDF too:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val getHostUdf = udf(getHost _)
val urls = urls.select(getHostUdf($"url") as "host")
```

Result will be exactly the same.